# VScode の Remote Developmentで Windows10 opensshサーバーに接続できない。

Tags: windows, vscode

VScode の Remote Developmentで Windows10のopensshサーバーに接続できません。
通常のコマンドプロンプトからssh接続できるのは確認しております。
windowsサーバーはopensshを使っております。

おそらくVscodeのRemote Developmentの拡張機能でアクセスするときになにか問題が起きていると考えられるのですが・・・
すみませんがご享受ください。

以下エラー文

```
[19:23:10.289] > 'bash' �́A����R�}���h�܂��͊O���R�}���h�A
> ����\�ȃv���O�����܂��̓o�b�` �t�@�C���Ƃ��ĔF������Ă��܂���B
> 
[19:23:10.608] "install" terminal command done
[19:23:10.608] Install terminal quit with output: ����\�ȃv���O�����܂��̓o�b�` �t�@�C���Ƃ��ĔF������Ă��܂���B
[19:23:10.608] Received install output: ����\�ȃv���O�����܂��̓o�b�` �t�@�C���Ƃ��ĔF������Ă��܂���B
[19:23:10.610] Stopped parsing output early. Remaining text: ����\�ȃv���O�����܂��̓o�b�` �t�@�C���Ƃ��ĔF������Ă��܂���B
[19:23:10.610] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[19:23:10.610] Resolver error: 
[19:23:10.614] TELEMETRY: {"eventName":"resolver","properties":{"outcome":"failure","reason":"UnparsableOutput","askedPw":"0","askedPassphrase":"0","asked2fa":"0","askedHostKey":"0","gotUnrecognizedPrompt":"0","remoteInConfigFile":"1"},"measures":{"resolveAttempts":1,"retries":1}}
```

VScode Insider版を使用してアクセスしたところ、以下のエラーでした。
(IPアドレスは*にしてあります。)

```
[08:50:07.449] > python@***.***.***.***'s password:
[08:50:07.449] Showing password prompt
[08:50:13.245] Got password response
[08:50:13.245] "install" wrote data to terminal: "*******"
[08:50:13.285] > 
> 
[08:50:13.538] > 'bash' �́A����R�}���h�܂��͊O���R�}���h�A
> ����\�ȃv���O�����܂��̓o�b�` �t�@�C���Ƃ��ĔF������Ă
> ��܂���B
[08:50:13.564] > 
> 
> 
> 
[08:50:13.813] "install" terminal command done
[08:50:13.814] Install terminal quit with output: ��܂���B
[08:50:13.814] Received install output: ��܂���B
[08:50:13.815] Stopped parsing output early. Remaining text: ��܂���B
[08:50:13.815] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[08:50:13.815] Resolver error: 
[08:50:13.820] TELEMETRY: {"eventName":"resolver","properties":{"outcome":"failure","reason":"UnparsableOutput","askedPw":"1","askedPassphrase":"0","asked2fa":"0","askedHostKey":"0","gotUnrecognizedPrompt":"0","remoteInConfigFile":"1"},"measures":{"resolveAttempts":1,"retries":1}}
[08:50:13.822] ------
```

Comment: 実際の挙動は確認できていないのですが、[ドキュメント](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh)によると現状WindowsホストはVS Code Insiderのみの対応のようですが、お使いのVSCodeはStableではなくInsider版ですか？

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。現在使用のVScodeはStable版です。Insider版というのが初耳なのですが、そちらを使用することで可能ということでしょうか・・・？一度やってみます。

Comment: Insider版インストールして実施したところ、おそらく同様のエラーが発生してしまいました。